# Java Libgdx: How do you add cells to a TiledMap?

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, tilemap

I'm trying to make a Side-Scrolling game that will allow you to place/remove tiles. I'm using the TileMap Editor to render the custom Tilemap but is there any way to add tiles? I have it where I can remove the tiles with .setTile(null) but is there anyway to get the properties from a tile in the TileMap Editor so that it can get the Texture/Tile to use so it can place the tile?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Cell` and fill that with a tile from the `TileMapTileSet`, then set that cell at **(x, y)** coordinates in a particular `Layer`.

For example, the following code sets the tile at **(32, 64)** in a layer to tile **42** from tile set *tileset_name*;

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get("some_layer_name");
Cell cell = new Cell();
TiledMapTileSet tileSet = map.getTileSets().getTileSet("tileset_name");
cell.setTile(tileSet.getTile(42)); /* or some other id, identifying the tile */
layer.setCell(32, 64, cell); // 32 and 64 being x and y coordinates
```

In the above code `map` is a `TiledMap`.